# How do I make a video, with some effects, from images?

Tags: linux, photos, video-editing, slideshow

I want to make a video/slideshow from several images with some effects in Linux!

What programs do u recommend excluding FFmpeg?

Comment: Any particular reason why you hate ffmpeg?

Comment: nope i don't hate ffmpeg, but i want to add some effect's on my images and some text to video! i can do that with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

If you're after something with a gui (I'm a command line freak, but I'd use a gui app for this too) [pitivi](http://www.pitivi.org), [lives](http://lives.sourceforge.net/), [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/), [Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/) or [cinelerra](http://cinelerra.org/) might do the job. Blender also does [video editing](http://www.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-242/video-sequence-editor/) (there seems to be nothing it can't do).

Or if you wait or a while you'll be able to get [Lightworks](http://ostatic.com/blog/powerful-video-editor-lightworks-released-as-open-source) - a full professional NLE.

Comment: On the contrary I need something to do the job from the command line

Comment: Ok then, have a look at Avisynth. (And another look at ffmpeg).
http://avisynth3.unite-video.com/

Comment: Interesting. I think it solves a question I made in Super User. I'll try then :)